# linker command failed when adding card.io sdk to project

Tags: ios, card.io

When I add the card.io sdk to my project i'm getting the following when trying to compile:

```
    duplicate symbol _CGSizeSwap in:
    /ProjectX/CardIO/libCardIO.a(CardIOShutterView.o)
    /ProjectX/CardIO/libCardIO.a(CardIODataEntryViewController.o)
duplicate symbol _CGSizeSwap in:
    /ProjectX/CardIO/libCardIO.a(CardIOShutterView.o)
    /ProjectX/CardIO/libCardIO.a(CardIOResource.o)
duplicate symbol _CGSizeSwap in:
    /ProjectX/CardIO/libCardIO.a(CardIOShutterView.o)
    /ProjectX/CardIO/libCardIO.a(CardIOModalActivityIndicator.o)
ld: 3 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

help appreciated [using xcode 4.6 & card.io version 3.0.4]

Comment: Hmmm. What Xcode version? Compiler/linker version? card.io SDK version? What are your linker flags?

Comment: I'm having this problem only with the simulator.

Comment: @JoshBleecherSnyder I'm using xcode 4.6 (latest) and card.io version 3.0.4 (latest) the other linkers are...
-ObjC -framework  CFNetwork -framework CoreData -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -lstdc++

Comment: @Garthex I havent tried it on a device yet, will report back

Comment: @Garthex et al: Thanks! I've reproduced the issue. We'll get a new release out very soon with a fix. I'll answer the question when it is out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Josh from card.io here. Thanks for reporting this!

It was a bug in the card.io iOS SDK release 3.0.4. We've just released 3.0.5; please give it a whirl at https://www.card.io/integrate/ios and confirm that it fixes the issue for you.

Comment: Josh, Another issue i noticed was that using card.io + ios 6 maps theres a conflict because the maps holds onto the EAGLContext so when switching between the map and payment view in the app i'm working on i need to call [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:nil];

Comment: @tinyfugu thanks! Any chance you'd be willing to email me at josh@card.io? I just want to make sure we fix this right for you...